# How to change websphere listener port

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-liberty

I try to run websphere liberty profile in some specific environment. Unfortunately server don't start, and I see in log:

> com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "java.net.SocketException: Permission denied com.ibm.ws.kernel.launch.internal.ServerCommandListener 150"

So I understand that I have to disable server command lister or to change it port (i can't allow to use this port). I can't find information where and how to set it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

- Login to WebSphere Admin Console
- Go to Servers -> Server Types -> WebSphere application servers
- Select the server's *name* link
- While at *Configuration* tab, under *Communications* section, click *Ports*
- You can now change the default ports for various listeners and tasks

**Update**: My apologies. I had not read the question correctly. In that case, you have to change it through a [property file](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc%2Fae%2Ftwlp_inst_bootstrap.html).

Note that I do not have WS Liberty profile installed, so I cannot verify this.

Answer (score 1):

You're running into an issue opening the server command port, a localhost-only ephemeral port that used for interprocess communication.

There is an APAR in the pipeline that will allow you to configure the port that is used, or to disable it completely. But understand that if you disable this port, certain server commands will stop working.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM89272

A related thread on the wasdev forum: 
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=3acdfcf2-0e10-4208-9d8d-ed82f37818aa#026a3eef-2c7f-4182-9b27-e298f1d0d849